# ToolBar Buttons Slide

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton, toolbar

I got a ToolBar with three UIButtons in it, how is it possible to switch between buttons like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPG6e.gif)?

I searched on the internet but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I didn't get your question properly :(
Try with SwipeGestures